# Join on one field condition based on another field

Tags: sql, oracle, join, conditional-statements

I am having trouble with a join. Since I'm working on a rather large procedure (1000+ lines) I have to make alot of cte's and joins. However this one seemed simple enough to me, but now I'mm stuck.

I want to join a table but only on fields which are

1. not in an invalid state if b is true (State !=1)
2. but only if they were turned into that state before X_date (`Status_time < x_date`)

Meaning that in some situations I will want a row where `state=1` because the `state=1` was set after `x_date`.

I think using a case would slow down peformance way to much to be viable. but I'm open to any suggestion.

Here is an example as I tried making to join first (it's larger but I have removed parts not connected with this problem)

```
 Left join contracts con4 
  on con4.owner_id = cu.cust_id
  and.......some condition
  and.......some condition
  and  (con4.contract_status != 1 and con4.status_time < cr.x_date)
```

Sample code

The code below try to do the same as the one above. I want to join because only one of the conditions is true and not both. (status != 1 AND b.status_time < x_date)

```
with sample_t as(
  select '123' cust_id, '' contract_status, sysdate x_date from dual),

  contract as(select '1' contract_status, '123' cust_id, sysdate+1 status_time from dual)

  select * from sample_t a
  left join contract b
  on a.cust_id = b.cust_id
  and (b.contract_status != '1' and b.status_time < x_date)
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and output.

Comment: No sample data, table structure and sample code -> no point in trying to help.

Comment: Seems like you need just an OR condition: `state = 1 OR Status_time < x_date`. When state is 1 the condition is true otherwise it will check the date.

Comment: not really sure what you mean by sample. but i have added a sample kind of. to the text. basically if you comment the last line the join will happen. with the last line i doesnt happen. I want the join to happen with the last line (if that makes any sense)

Comment: We're asking for some sample data from each table and the expected output all formatted either in a tabular form or as create table, and insert statements, such that we have data to test our responses against.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. PS You are not clear; your bullets 1 & 2 contradict the sentence right after. Consider enumerating all the condition combinations & telling us which ones satisfy you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your requirement?

```
and  (con4.contract_status != 1 and con4.status_time < cr.x_date
  or  con4.contract_status = 1 and con4.status_time > cr.x_date)
```

You haven't stated what is to happen when con4.status_time = cr.x_date.